# Почему от добавления printf зависит значение переменной? Или влияние printf на корректность работы программы

Tags: c, printf

Задача:
Создать функцию, которая разбивает строку символов на слова. Слова разделены пробелом. Функция возвращает массив указателей, каждый из которых ссылается на массив символов (слова). Слова должны заканчиваться нуль-терминатором.

Пример кода:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int count_words(char *str)   //подсчет количества слов в заданной строке
{
int i;
int words;

i = 0;
words = 0;
while (str[i] != '\0')
{
    if (str[i] == ' ')
        words++;
    i++;
}
words = words + 1;
return (words);
}

char    **split_whitespaces(char *str)
{
int i;
int j;
int k;
int len;    //длина слова
int w;
char    **dest;  //целевой массив

i = 0;
k = 0;
j = 0;

len = 0;

w = 0;
w = count_words(str);

dest = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * w);  //выделение памяти под массив указателей

while (str[i] != '\0')
{
    while (str[i] != ' ' && str[i] != '\0')  //определяем длину каждого слова
    {
        i++;
        len++;
    }
    len++;  //для добавления нуль-терминатора
    //printf("len = %d\n", len);  //волшебный printf
    dest[k] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * len); //выделение памяти под конкретное слово
    dest[k][len - 1] = '\0'; 
    len = 0;
    k++;
    i++;
}
i = 0;
k = 0;
while (i < w)  //наполнение ранее созданных массивов
{
    j = 0;
    while (dest[i][j] != '\0')
    {
        dest[i][j] = str[k];
        j++;
        k++;
    }
    k++;
    i++;
}
return (dest);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
char    str[15] = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', ' ', 'g', 'o', '\0'};
char    **word;

word = split_whitespaces(str);
printf("%s\n%s\n%s", word[0], word[1], word[2]);

return (0);
}
```

Вопрос/проблема: 
Если не прописывать "волшебный printf", то длина каждого массива будет равна 2, не зависимо от длины слова. Если же прописать printf, то в итоге получим необходимый результат. В чем подвох? Почему так происходит? Какое влияние printf оказывает на значение переменной?

Comment: Эта функция в принципе не работает, потому что `malloc` имеет полное право выделить обнулённую память, и условие `dest[i][j] != '\0'` сразу же нарушится и массив ничем не заполнится.

Comment: Кстати уже есть стандартная функция для разделения на слова

Comment: Есть то есть.. в моем же случае это обучающее задание))

Answer (score 0):

У Вас тут слишком много ошибок, что бы разобраться, какая из них - самая главная.

Для начала - совет. Объявление массива символов:

```
char    str[15] = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', ' ', 'g', 'o', '\0'};
```

Полностью эквивалентно гораздо более простому и понятному:

```
char    str[] = {"Hello, World go"};
```

Далее... Подозреваю, что записывая условие в операторе while таким образом:

```
while (str[i] != ' ' && str[i] != '\0')
```

Вы, не предполагали, что записали вот это:

```
while ((str[i] !=  (' ' && str[i])) != '\0')
```

Приоритет && выше приоритета операции сравнения !=

Ещё по поводу функции count_words. А что будет, если слова отделены друг от друга  ДВУМЯ пробелами? А тремя? А знаком пунктуации?

Ещё бросилось в глаза:

```
dest[k][len - 1] = '\0';
```

Но вы только что делали len++ ?! Кстати говоря - совершенно напрасно. По выходу из цикла len УЖЕ указывает на разделитель слов.

Короче: убирайте ошибки одну за другой, а там уже будет видно....

Comment: С приоритетом ошибка у вас : сначала != потом && . https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

Comment: && не только ниже приоритетом, но и является точкой следования.

Comment: @Sergey это всё не ошибки, а мелкие недочёты, а с приоритетом ошибка уже у вас.

Comment: Спасибо! Будем исправлять!

Comment: Дополнительный len++ на выходе из цикла я поставил для того, чтобы выделить в памяти еще 1 байт для '\0'. Это было уже добавлено в процессе поиска ошибки, т.е. изначально я сразу прописывал в malloc(sizeof(char) * (len + 1)), и, соответственно, вариант задания исходной строки в main - тоже следствие экспериментов.

Comment: @AlexGlebe "С приоритетом ошибка у вас " - да, действительно! Сослепу не разглядел, перепутал != и |=

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось, проблема заключалось вот в чем:

```
dest[k] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * len); //выделение памяти под конкретное слово
dest[k][len - 1] = '\0';
```

После выделения памяти таким образом нужно сразу заполнить его любыми символами, добавив:

```
dest[k] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * len);
while (j < len)
{
 dest[k][j] = ' ';
 j++;
 }
dest[k][len - 1] = '\0';
```

Теперь, при обращении к элементам массива dest для его наполнения, программа отрабатывает корректно.

А по-хорошему, переделать код так, чтобы массивы заполнялись сразу нужными значениями.

P.S. Почему добавление строки printf все исправляло, я так и не понял.

Comment: вам наверное лучше бы учится на писателя, а не на программиста

Comment: Почему Вы так считаете?